# Publish specific version that is not accessible for everyone while doing in-app purchase test

Tags: android, in-app

I've published MyApplication1.0.apk to google play store. Now in MyApplication2.0.apk I've implemented in-app purchases that I want to do testing on. I did add my email to test-accounts @GoogleConsole, but how do I test MyApplication2.0 not 1.0 which is in production? Do I have to somehow publish it (so it's not available for everyone, just me)? How to do that?

Comment: you can publish it on secure alpha and beta channels from publish console.

Comment: Do I've to publish it on both (alpha AND beta) or can I use one? What's the difference? Will it be accessible for random people (I would not like that)

Comment: you can check the help section for your relative queries here. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en